# perl -- add double quote and right angle bracket at end of join

Tags: html, perl, join

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# prints dir list of .jpg filenames to screen
# and adds HTML markup for flexbox

use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::Autoformat;
my $file;
my $nfilename;
my $first = '<img src="';
my $last = '" style="width:100%"> ';
my $title = 'title = "';
my $estr = '">';
my $dir = "/home/clair/cp-perl/";
my $mylist;
opendir(DIR, $dir) or die $!;

while ($file = readdir(DIR)) {

# Use a regular expression to ignore files beginning with a period
next if ($file =~ m/^\./);
next if (substr $file, -1) ne "g";

#***************************************
# get rid of extension and replace hyphen with space   

$nfilename=$file;
$nfilename=~s/.jpg//;
$nfilename =~ s/-/ /g;

# ****************************************
#capitalizewords in filename to be a title

my $formatted = autoformat $nfilename, { case => 'highlight' };

chomp($nfilename);

# ****************************************
$mylist = join("",$first, $file, $last, $title, $nfilename, $estr);

# ************************* 
# thanks to George Mavridis - stackoverflow
$mylist =~ s/[\r\n]+//;
$mylist .="\n";
# *************************

print $mylist;

}
closedir(DIR);
exit 0;
```

This is the first 3 lines of output I get now:

```
<pre>
<img src="out-of-the-night.jpg" style="width:100%"> title = "Out of the Night
"><img src="homage-to-borgeson.jpg" style="width:100%"> title = "Homage to Borgeson
"><img src="autumn-in-vermont.jpg" style="width:100%"> title = "Autumn in Vermont
</pre>
```

Those first two characters are supposed to be at the END of the lines, like this:

```
<pre>
<img src="out-of-the-night-sm.jpg" style="width:100%"> title = "Out of the Night">
<img src="homage-to-borgeson.jpg" style="width:100%"> title = "Homage to Borgeson">
<img src="autumn-in-vermont-sm.jpg" style="width:100%"> title = "Autumn in Vermont">
</pre>
```

here is the join line:

```
$mylist = join("",$first, $file, $last, $title, $nfilename, $estr);
print $mylist;
```

This is the $estr declaration: my $estr = '">';
I have tried innumerable version of this -- this is only the current one.

I want to know how to make those two characters show up at the END of the line and not the beginning of the next line.

I've worked hours on this one thing and also two hours the day before yesterday trying to get the forum to accept my question.

Thank you so much for any help. Clair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are hundreds of ways to solve this problem, one of them is:

$mylist (before printing it) in your example contains:

```
<img src="out-of-the-night.jpg" style="width:100%"> title = "Out of the Night
">
```

removing the linefeed in between, and adding it at the end of the string

```
$mylist =~ s/[\r\n]+//;
$mylist .="\n";
```

would fix that.

BTW: The '> "' at the end of $last also seems wrong.

Comment: George --Thank you so much.

Comment: I now have perfect lines to drop into the flexbox <div> thanks to you -- and YES the end of $last is there to complete the CSS <style="width=100%"> phrase. (I wrote this to greatly lesson typing and it does that in spades.

Answer (score 2):

The string in `$nfilename` apparently ends with a line feed. Did you read a line from a file and leave the line feed in? [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) can be used to remove trailing line feed from variables.

Comment: i had a zstroke recently which destroyed 3 fingerd on left hand - difficult to type so this script will  save me much typing. I am an artist and will be making galley pagex to display images. You con make a useable directpru with entries like x-1.jpg, x-2.jpg, etc. that will work-- just chancge the $dir variable.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if you find use for following code.

It looks for JPG files in local directory and generates web page

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $dir = '.';
my @files;

push @files, $_ while glob('*.jpg');

my $title = 'Pictures in JPEG format';
my $space = "\n\t\t\t";
my $style = 'width:100%';

my $html  = '
<html>
    <head>
        <title>$title</title>
    </head>
    <body>';

for (@files) {
    /(.*?)\.jpg/;
    my $title = $1;
    $title =~ s/[-_]/ /g;
    $html .= "$space title = \"\u$title\"";
    $html .= "$space<img src=\"$_\" style=\"$style\">";
}

$html .= '
    </body>
</html>';

say $html;
```

Output

```
<html>
        <head>
                <title>Pictures in JPEG format</title>
        </head>
        <body>
                         title = "File 08"
                        <img src="file-08.jpg" style="width:100%">
                         title = "File 09"
                        <img src="file-09.jpg" style="width:100%">
                         title = "File 01"
                        <img src="file_01.jpg" style="width:100%">
                         title = "File 02"
                        <img src="file_02.jpg" style="width:100%">
                         title = "File 03"
                        <img src="file_03.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </body>
</html>
```